# Find the generating function of $S_n$(Please check my idea)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

$Q)$ Let the $S_n$ be the number of the  positive roots $(x,y,z)$ of the $x+2y+3z=n$, $n \geq 6$ (I.e. $x>0, y>0$ and $z>0$)

Find the generating function $g(x)$ of $S_n + S_{n+1} + S_{n+2}$

---

Say $f(x) = S_6 x^6 +S_7x^7+ S_8x^8...$ (generating function of the $S_n$)

When I computed the $f(x)$, $f(x)$ = $x^6 \over (1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)$

So here is my question

In the solution, it said the generating function, $g(x)$ = $(1+ {1 \over x} + {1 \over x^2})f(x)$

But, In my thought

$(1+ {1 \over x} + {1 \over x^2})f(x) = S_6x^5 + S_6 x^4 + S_7x^5 + \sum_{n=6} ^\infty (S_n + S_{n+1} + S_{n+2})x^n =  S_6x^5 + S_6 x^4 + S_7x^5 + g(x)$

(I.e. $g(x) = (1+ {1 \over x} + {1 \over x^2})f(x) - (S_6x^5 + S_6 x^4 + S_7x^5) $ with $S_6 = 1$ and $S_7 =1$)

The reason why $S_6 =1$ is there is a only root $(1,1,1)$. Vice versa $S_7 =1$, having a only root $(2,1,1)$

So my guess is the solution is false. Is my thought right? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you computed $f(x)$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, yes I did.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang Personally, I don't see why the things you describe should be a problem.

Comment: @Gae.S., Hmm... I edited my post. What I've described is the $g(x)$ is different comparing the solution sheet and mine. In my thought, the $g(x) = \sum_{n=6}(S_{n}+S_{n+1}+S_{n+2})x^n$, So I should subtract term $x^5$ and $x^4$ parts considering the $(1+{1 \over x}+{1 \over x^2})f(x)$. Therefore I guess solution is wrong.